# Need to allow for variable model names in my app using RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The app returns the number of records based on a variable name in my route. So if I have a "Person" model and a "Car" model (or any number of other ones), I want to be able to assign any of these to a variable and get results from it.

I've tried:

```
@model = params[:model]
@model.find(:all).count
```

and I get the error:

```
undefined method `find' for "Person":String
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: FYI, you should be doing `Person.count` instead of `Person.find(:all).count`. The first way uses `select count(*)`, the second way queries the entire table into memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@model = params[:model].constantize
@model.find(:all).count
```

Constantize turns a string in to a constant.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to mark this response as the answer so other people with the same question will know it was successfully answered at a glance.